# Python function argument passing sequence

Tags: python, argument-passing

Following code is incorrect:

```
def add(a, b, c):
    return a + b + c
args = (2, 3)

add(a = 1, *args)
TypeError: add() got multiple values for keyword argument 'a'
```

I've seen some example in [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists), but I still don't know why there's an error, can anybody explain in detail?

Comment: I note that the a search for ["got multiple values for keyword argument"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22got+multiple+values+for+keyword+argument%22) yields plenty of hits. Do any of those questions fit your case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When applying the arguments, Python *first* fills in the positional arguments, *then* the keyword arguments.

In your specific case, `*args` is then applied firsts, so the first positional argument is passed `2`, the second is passed `3`. The first argument is `a` here.

*Then* the `a = 1` is applied, and Python finds that you already applied a value to it.

In other words, Python cannot and will not take positional arguments out of consideration when you use one as a keyword argument. Just because you used `a` as keyword argument does not make it ineligible as a positional argument.